# React-Redux error: 'visible' is undefined

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement a sidebar function coming from https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/sidebar/#types-sidebar. But I'm still getting the undefined 'visible' error. I want to pass my mapped state to props 'visible' from my index to the navbar.js on the buttons when disabled.

So I created a reducer 'reducers/App.js':

```
    import {
      HIDE_CLICK,
      SHOW_CLICK,
      HIDE_SIDE_BAR,
    } from "../actions/app";

    const initialState = {
      visible: false
    };

    const appReducer = (state = initialState, {type}) => {
      switch(type) {
        case HIDE_CLICK:
          return {
            ...state,
            visible: false,
          }
        case SHOW_CLICK:
          return{
            ...state,
            visible: true,
          }
        case HIDE_SIDE_BAR:
          return {
            ...state,
            visible: false,
          }
      };
    }

    export default appReducer;
```

Then its action 'action/App.js':

```
    export const HIDE_CLICK = "HIDE_CLICK";
    export const SHOW_CLICK = "SHOW_CLICK";
    export const HIDE_SIDE_BAR = "HIDE_SIDE_BAR";

    export const handleHideClick = () => ({
      type: HIDE_CLICK,
    })

    export const handleShowClick = () => ({
      type: SHOW_CLICK,
    })

    export const handleSideBarHide = () => ({
      type: HIDE_SIDE_BAR,
    })
```

Now my component contains: 'NavBar/index.js'

```
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import NavBar from "./NavBar";

    import { handleHideClick, handleShowClick, handleSideBarHide } from "../../redux/actions/app";

    /* istanbul ignore next */
    const mapStateToProps = state => ({
      isAuthenticated: state.authentication.authenticated,
      visible: state.app.visible
    });

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return{
        handleHideClick: () => dispatch(handleHideClick),
        handleShowClick: () => dispatch(handleShowClick),
        handleSideBarHide: () => dispatch(handleSideBarHide)
      }
    };

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps,
      mapDispatchToProps,
    )(NavBar);
```

and my 'NavBar/NavBar.js'

```
    import React from "react";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
    import { Container, Menu, Button, Sidebar,Segment, Icon, Header, Image } from "semantic-ui-react";

    export const ShowSideBar = ({
      handleShowClick,
      handleHideClick,
      handleSideBarHide
    }) => (
        <div>
          <Button.Group>
            <Button disabled={visible} onClick={handleShowClick}>
              Show sidebar
            </Button>
            <Button disabled={!visible} onClick={handleHideClick}>
              Hide sidebar
            </Button>
          </Button.Group>

          <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
            <Sidebar
              as={Menu}
              animation='overlay'
              icon='labeled'
              inverted
              onHide={handleSideBarHide}
              vertical
              visible={visible}
              width='thin'
            >
    ...
```

)

and lastly defined the app reducer on my root reducer:

```
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";

    import authentication from "./authentication";
    import app from "./app";

    const rootReducer = combineReducers({
      authentication,
      app
    });

    export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: try to change action as following for return JSON 

export const handleHideClick = () => ( return {
      type: HIDE_CLICK,
    })

Comment: I will need to use redux actions and reducers to follow the current format.

Comment: wild guess: instead of `disabled={visible}` use `disabled={this.props.visible}`

Comment: I'm getting this error now : ```Failed to compile
./src/redux/reducers/app.js
  Line 28:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Answer (score 0):

You need to list all the props you need or just don't destructure them:

```
export const ShowSideBar = ({
  handleShowClick,
  handleHideClick,
  handleSideBarHide,
  visible
}) => (
  ....
)
```

or `export const ShowSideBar = (props) => (...)` and access everything with `props.`

Comment: I'm getting this new error: ```I'm getting this error now : Failed to compile ./src/redux/reducers/app.js Line 28: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression no-unused-expressions Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.```

Comment: my mistake, I forgot the return statement on the default from the switch case